# Dirac delta limit representation check?

Tags: special-functions

It is well known that the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-plane)

$$\eta_y(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$

Provides a limit representation of the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\lim_{y\to0}\eta_y(x)=\delta(x)$. In an attempt to verify this fact in Mathematica, I take:

```
Limit[y/(x^2+y^2) , y->0]
```

> `0`

which gives the proper result for all `x` except for `x=0`. In fact, I would have preferred the `Limit` function to actually return `Pi DiracDelta[x]`, similarly to what happens if we evaluate `FourierTransform[1,x,w]`. Nevertheless, we can also plot, e.g.:

```
Plot[y/(x^2 + y^2) /. y -> 10^-1, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

and convince ourselves that for ever-smaller `y` the function indeed approaches a delta function.

Now, consider changing the sign of `x^2` in the above expression:

```
Plot[y/(-x^2 + y^2) /. y -> 5^-1, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

In this case, apart from the non-zero region around `x=0` there also appear negative and positive infinities symmetrically on both sides. Considering that the normalization changes a bit:

```
Integrate[y/(-x^2 + y^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> [image]

one might think that

$$\lim_{y^2\to 0+i0}\eta_y(x)=\lim_{y^2\to 0+i0}\frac{i}{\pi}\frac{y}{-x^2+y^2}$$

is also a limit representation of the delta function, if we take `y` to zero along a path such that `y^2` is slightly complex. However, so far this is just an assumption, and the `Limit` routine cannot be used to verify this as we have seen above. Is it possible to use Mathematica to verify this claim?

Comment: Just for completeness, I think your second graph is not for $y=0.1$

Comment: Also if you have `y= I w` you just get `I w/(-x^2-w^2)=-I w/(x^2+w^2)`, i.e. basically the same as before.

Comment: @mikuszefski You are right, it was actually `y=1/5`, I fixed it. Also, nice observation! Even though I'd like to keep `y` mostly real (due to its interpretation in my specific case) this shows that analytic continuation to complex `y` ensures that it is still the delta function. You should post this as an answer and I will upvote and accept!

Comment: (1) Definitely a math rather than Mathematica question. (2) Usually delta-type functionals are defined in real space. Might or might not make sense to try to extend to C in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Comment: @m_goldberg You are right. I will delete this question in a couple hours, since it is off topic here, if no one comments to suggest otherwise until then.

Comment: @Kagaratsch the main question remains: ***Is it possible to use Mathematica to verify this claim?*** Would you consider this a *Mathematica* question?

Comment: @mikuszefski I would give this the benefit of the doubt, even if only to answer "no" (but more knowledgeable folks could say a lot about the symbolic capabilities of MMA and such). (Voting to leave open)

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes, that is what I thought too, when asking the question. OK, since the opinions are split, I will not delete the question.

Comment: BTW I'll not post my comment from above as answer, as it only deals with a mathematical but not the *Mathematica* aspect.

Comment: There is a math question one could extract and post here at math.stackexchange.com, but that is not this question. This question is "How do I compute limits of distributions in mathematica? It keeps computing the limit as functions instead!

Comment: @Hurkyl Indeed, help, how do I compute a limit of distributions? Seems to me that the question is pretty evident from the above and I would love to know the answer.